# Is there a Javascript and Java implementation of a good CSPRNG

Tags: randomness, pseudo-random-generator

I need to use a cryptographically secure pseudo random number generator in my client running Javascript and in my server running Java.

Is there a well-known implementation of a good CSPRNG in both Java and Javascript?

If not, is there a pseudo-code description of a good CSPRNG I can implement myself in Java and Javascript?

Comment: Why do they have to be the same algorithm? Could you run node.js on the server side? I think your question would be better off on a different site. This site is more about theoretical aspects of crypto. StackOverflow or IT Security could be better sites. If you want me to migrate the question, let me know.

Comment: for some inspiration you could have a look into how the linux kernel handles the /dev/urandom csprng (here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=static+void+extract_buf%28struct+entropy_store+*r%2C+__u8+*out%29 ). It looks to be the application of a SHA1 hash which the output is paritally feedback to the randomsource entropy source. To have hashing SHA256 in javacript for implementing the desired "CS"PRNG you could benefit from the standord javascript crypt lib https://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/

Comment: It has been asked on this forum already and to how I perceived it an XOR combination of two PNRG outputs could be a way to allow for some better results. Hence when available I assume the browsers (i.e. Mozilla's `RandomSource.getRandomValues()` function could be eventually "mixed in your sha256 seed hash feedback pnrg feedback".